# How to add a linux user in single line?

Tags: bash, shell, redhat

Is there any option to add a user in single line. it includes the password. Dont prompt anything.

OS=RHEL 5.5

Answer (score 19):

You can use `useradd` to set everything including the password.  The password must be encrypted already, but you can use `openssl` to make the md5 password if you want to just specify the plain text password:

```
useradd -u 12345 -g users -d /home/username -s /bin/bash -p $(echo mypasswd | openssl passwd -1 -stdin) username
```

You may want to exclude this from your history, though, if you are using a plaintext password in the command.  You can prepend a space before the command to exclude it from history.  If you are running this command on a lot of machines, you may just want to generate the password once and use it in the command directly:

```
useradd -u 12345 -g users -d /home/username -s /bin/bash -p '$1$NNfXfoym$Eos.OG6sFMGE8U6ImwBqT1' username
```

Comment: I don't think the `-u` is needed, in this case, unless you want to specifically choose a certain UID.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use something like this:

```
adduser --uid 3434 --password my_password my_login
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks that `useradd` will encrypt the password with crypt. If you'd rather use other method (MD5, SHA256, SHA512), you can create the user with `useradd` and set the password with `chpasswd`, You can run:

```
useradd <options> && echo username:password | chpasswd --crypt-method=SHA512
```

Your system-wide default password encryption method is set in /etc/login.defs in variable ENCRYPT_METHOD. `&&` causes `chpasswd` to run only if user creation with `useradd` was successful (exit code of 0)

Answer (score 3):

A late arrival to the game - RHEL 7.1 - the following thing works. Creates a SUDO user, does not encrypt password, and immediately logs in as the new user:

```
U=youzerneim; P="pswrd"; adduser $U; echo $P | passwd $U --stdin; usermod -aG wheel $U; su - $U
```

Answer (score 1):

useradd -u <uid> -G <group> -d /home/<user home dir> -p password -m

-u for UID
-d for home directory
-m for creating the home directory as mentioned in -d option

Well there are many more options depending on the flavour of linux.
You can always do ... man useradd OR man adduser